# Azure Devops: AzurePowerShell@5 cannot calls other function

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, yaml

I have a powershell script MyScript.ps1 which runs without any issue on my local machine.

```
$var1 = "var1"
$var2 = "var2"

$result = Function-A -var1 $var1 -var2 $var2




Function-A{
    param(
        [string] $var1, 
        [string] $var2
    )

   #some logics here.
}
```

I call this script in my Azure DevOps Yaml script via the task AzurePowerShell@5

```
        steps: 
          - task: AzurePowerShell@5 
            displayName: 'Execute PS script'
            env:
                SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: '${{ variables.azureConnection }}'
              scriptType: 'FilePath'
              scriptPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/MyScript.ps1'
              azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
```

I keep getting error below:

> ##[error]The term 'Function-A' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

> ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error]The term 'Function-A' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

> ##[debug]Exit code: 1

Reading around, I think I can solve this by grouping them into a module and then call them that way.  However, that's a lot of overhead for something simple like this...please point me into the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/chuckles

Silly ADO, so all functions have to be declared earlier in the file before it is called.

```
$var1 = "var1"
$var2 = "var2"

Function-A{
    param(
        [string] $var1, 
        [string] $var2
    )

   #some logics here.
}



$result = Function-A -var1 $var1 -var2 $var2
```